# Create an optimal query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm newbie in sql, I want to get data from this table :

```
id       pseudo         amount      date
1        test1          34          2015-09-16 09:21:51
2        test2          78          2015-09-14 09:21:51
3        test3          896         2015-10-01 09:21:51
4        test4          67          2015-11-16 09:21:51
5        test5          12          2015-09-23 09:21:51
6        test6          19          2015-09-09 09:21:51
```

I want to get in one query the ligne with the biggest `amount` and the last 3 lignes order by date...I can do this in 2 query but I want the optimal option for this problem. Can you help me please ? Sorry for my english :)

```
pseudo                amount
test3                 896
test4                 67
test5                 12
test1                 34
test2                 78
```

Comment: post sample output also

Comment: `UNION` the two queries together. (Will return 3 rows if the one with biggest amount also is one of the last 3 rows!)

Comment: Use two queries with Union

Comment: Is this the best way ?

Comment: how you would distinguish rows?

Comment: I cant understand your output rows.

Comment: The first ---- > is the big amount and last 4 order by date desc

Comment: How come your expected result has 5 rows? 3 + 1 = 4. (At most.) What if a tie, e.g. 4 rows with same last timestamp?

Comment: @jarlh I have 5 rows in the result

Comment: Now I see...! Sorry.

Comment: @HareaCosticla please find the below answer

Answer (score 0):

based on your assumed data we can achieve this Using **MAX** conditions and **CTE**

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (id int, pseudo varchar(5), amount int, date varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (id, pseudo, amount, date)
VALUES
    (1, 'test1', 34, '2015-09-16 09:21:51'),
    (2, 'test2', 78, '2015-09-14 09:21:51'),
    (3, 'test3', 896, '2015-10-01 09:21:51'),
    (4, 'test4', 67, '2015-11-16 09:21:51'),
    (5, 'test5', 12, '2015-09-23 09:21:51'),
    (6, 'test6', 19, '2015-09-09 09:21:51')
;
;WITH CTE AS (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TN ORDER BY TN) RW 
from (
select id,
    pseudo,
    amount,
    MAX(pseudo)OVER( ORDER BY amount desc )TN from @Table1 )T )
,cte2 as (
Select top 3 pseudo,
amount 
from CTE 
    WHERE RW = 2  order by amount)
Select pseudo,amount from CTE WHERE RW = 1 AND pseudo <> 'test6'
UNION ALL 
select  pseudo,amount from cte2
```